# How to use consistent hashing to allocate multiple servers for the same key?

Tags: architecture, system-design, consistent-hashing

I'm reading a system design article about design ticketmaster. It mentions:
*We can use the Consistent Hashing to allocate application servers for both ActiveReservationService and WaitingUserService based upon the ‘ShowID’. This way, all reservations and waiting users of a particular show will be handled by a certain set of servers. Let’s assume for load balancing our Consistent Hashing allocates three servers for any Show*
But my understanding of consistent hashing is we will calculate hash(showID), and find this value on the hash ring, then go clockwise and find the next node which will be the server to use. Thus I imagine the showID will always go to the same server. How we allocates three servers for any Show?
Thank you!